# Cypress: Click sticking the flow

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

When I click on a button that is triggering the prompt window, the flow is sticking here and I can't do anything. What could be the problem?

```
it('Test case', () => {
  cy.get('iframe').iframe(() => {
    cy.get('.button').eq(0).click();
  });

  // Process stopping here

  cy.contains('Please enter data').click()
  cy.on('window:confirm', (str) => {
    expect(str).to.equal('Please enter data')
  })
  cy.on('window:confirm', () => true);
});
```

[image: Test Runner Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

`cy.on(event, callback)` will only catch predefined events (see [Catalog of events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events)).

You probably want to [stub](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub#Method) instead.

```js
it('Test window confirm was called', () => {

  const win = cy.state('window')
  cy.stub(win, 'confirm')

  cy.get('iframe').iframe(() => {
    cy.get('.button').eq(0).click();
  });

  cy.window().its('confirm').should('be.calledWith', 'Please enter data')

});
```

**Tested with Cypress fiddle**

```js
/// <reference types="@cypress/fiddle" />

const test = {
  html: `
    <button onclick="window.confirm('test message')"></button>
  `,
  test: `
    const win = cy.state('window')
    cy.stub(win, 'confirm')

    cy.get('button').click()

    cy.window().its('confirm').should('be.calledWith', 'test message')  // passes
  `
}
it('run test', () => {
  cy.runExample(test)
})
```